# Как заставить winston логировать error в один файл, а info в другой

Tags: javascript, node.js, логирование

```
let logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
        name: 'error',
        filename: __dirname + `/../logs/error.log`,
        level: 'error',
        json: false
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
        name: 'info',
        filename: __dirname + `/../logs/info.log`,
        level: 'info',
        json: false,

    }),
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
        level: 'debug',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true
    })
]
});
```

Этот код пишет error как в файл error.log, так и в info.log. В документации так и указано, но не смог найти, возможность настройки, по типу maxLevel. Это возможно с winston?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать врапер типо такого:

```
'use strict';

const winston = require('winston');


const info = new winston.Logger({
    levels: {
        trace: 0,
        input: 1,
        verbose: 2,
        prompt: 3,
        debug: 4,
        info: 5,
        data: 6,
        help: 7,
        warn: 8,
        error: 9
    },
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            name: 'info',
            filename:  __dirname + `/../logs/info.log`,
            level: 'info',
            json: false,
            prettyPrint: true,
            colorize: false,
            silent: false,
            timestamp: false,
        })
    ]
});


const err = new winston.Logger({
    levels: {
        trace: 0,
        input: 1,
        verbose: 2,
        prompt: 3,
        debug: 4,
        info: 5,
        data: 6,
        help: 7,
        warn: 8,
        error: 9
    },
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            name: 'error',
            filename:  __dirname + `/../logs/error.log`,
            level: 'error',
            json: false,
            prettyPrint: true,
            colorize: false,
            silent: false,
            timestamp: false,
        })
    ]
});

const exps = {

    info: function (msg) {
        info.info(msg);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        err.error(msg);
    },
    log: function (level, msg) {
        const lvl = exps[level];
        lvl(msg);
    }
};

module.exports = exps;
```

Теперь в основном файле:

```
const logger = require('./winstonwrapper');

logger.info("This is fine"); //это запишется в info.log
logger.error("This is error"); //это запишется в error.log
logger.log("info", "This is fine too"); //это запишется в info.log
logger.log("error", "This is also error"); //это запишется в error.log
```